# Hover an image with AMP-Pinterest's PinIt button

Tags: html, amp-html

I added AMP-Pinterest to my AMPed page. I'd like to set the propery
`data-pin-hover="true"` to get the PinIt button on the image. For some reason it doesn't work.

Here is what I have so far:

**That's in `<head>`:**

```
 <script async custom-element="amp-pinterest" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-pinterest-0.1.js"></script>
```

(and of course other AMP stuff)

**That's in `<body>`:**

```
<amp-pinterest height=28 width=56
    data-do="buttonPin"
    data-url="URL"
    data-media="IMG_URL"
    data-pin-hover="true"
    data-description="DESC">
</amp-pinterest>
```

I also added `data-pin-nopin="false"` and `data-pin-no-hover="false"` to my `amp-img's` declaration (just in case, if it's not by default set to false. More info here: https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-pinterest):

```
<amp-img alt="NAME" src="IMG_URL" width="600"
height="400" layout="responsive"  data-pin-nopin="false"
data-pin-no-hover="false" />
```

But it still doesn't work (the PinIt button shows up above/below `amp-img`).

**Question:**
Now I'm wondering if I did something wrong or it's simply not supported using AMP-Pinterest to hover an image? (I can't find any example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, this option doesn't to be available for amp-pinterest at the moment (*going through the docs and other examples*). However, if you don't prefer for the Pin It button to not appear above or below, you can instead have it embedded in the image, as seen in the [amp-pinterest samples](https://ampbyexample.com/components/amp-pinterest/):

> **Embed pin widget**
>
> To embed the pin widget, set `data-do` to `embedPing`. The `data-url` attribute must contain the fully-qualified URL of the Pinterest resource.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't want to point to a Pinterest resource but to an image on my server. But that's ok - I wanted to make sure if I did't something wrong trying to hover an image. I think I will put this button below or above in this case. Thanks a lot!